# Could not enter data: No database selected

Tags: php, database

Here is the code I am getting a error Could not enter data: No database selected
I tried doing this code on localhost.I am not able to figure out the problem as I have created the database mb as well and the table as well.

```
<HTML> <HEAD>
<TITLE>Sample Site</TITLE> </HEAD>
<BODY>
<body text="Blue" bgcolor="Bisque"> <h1 align="center">User query...!
</h1> <?php
if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','','');

if(! $conn ) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$messege = $_POST['messege'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO users ". "(name,email,subject,messege) ". 
"VALUES('$name','$email','$subject', '$messege')";
$conn->select_db('mb');
$retval = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); if(! $retval ) {
die('Could not enter data: ' . mysqli_error($conn)); }
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysqli_close($conn); }else {
?>
<form method = "post" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width = "400" border = "0" > <tr>
 <td width = "100">Name</td> <td><input name = "name" type = "text"
id = "name"></td> </tr>
<tr>
<td width = "100">Email</td> <td><input name = "email" type = "text"
id = "email"></td> </tr>
<tr>
<td width = "100">Subject</td> <td><input name = "subject" type = "text"
id = "subject"></td> </tr>
<tr>
<td width = "100">Messege</td> <td><input name = "messege" type = "text"
id = "messege"></td> </tr>
<tr>
<td width = "100"> </td> <td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width = "100"> </td> <td>
<input name = "add" type = "submit" id = "add" value = "Add user">
</td> </tr>
</table> </form>
<?php }
?> </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_database_name");
```

or after your connection is estabilished you can select the database with a separate function:

```
mysqli_select_db($conn, "my_database_name");
```

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_connect contains 4 parameters and you have to add fourth parameter as database name i.e

> mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

Answer (score 0):

There is error in your `mysqli_connect` function. 
it should be

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","databaseName");
```

instead of

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','','');
```

Answer (score 0):

Its problem with your `mysqli_connect`. try connection with with below code

```
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect('servername', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers provided, you should be using prepared statements. You are using MYSQLI.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `users`(`name`, `email`, `subject`,`messege`) VALUES (?, ?, ?,?)");//use placeholders
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $name,$email, $subject, $message);//bind placeholders to values.no need to escape. 
if($stmt->execute() == true){
  echo 'Successfully saved using prepared statements';
} else {
  echo 'Error!Because: '.$stmt->error;
  exit;
```

}

Comment: That error went away but now this error is coming 
 Could not enter data: Unknown column 'messege' in 'field list'

Comment: that is your mistake. Your spelling may be wrong. is it 'messege' or 'message'? confirm with your database

Answer (score 0):

Add your username and database name

```
 $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','username here','','databasename here');
```